# How do I light up bookshelfs?

Tags: light

What type of lamp and settings should I use to achieve any of these ([link 1](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a6/fc/3f/a6fc3f2369542c5db65facade891bb93.jpg), [link 2](https://www.manufacturer.lighting/file/upload/201703/30/230625291.jpg), [link 3](http://thecharleygirl.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/10-hot-led-strip-lighting-design-ideas-electricians-in-croydon-brilliant-led-shelf-intended-for-14.jpg), [link 4](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/ac/1e/c3/ac1ec34efaab4f3e57cf59b88c3ebb40.jpg)) effects on my bookshelfs?

I only have sky texture and a sun in my scene and no ceiling.

[image]

Comment: You should place lamps or emitting geometry near the top of the shelves, just like in the references? Look at the references, there are many lamps, start by recreating that setup.

Answer (score 1):

Simply make the shelf and add a stripes of "light" to every part U wanna have lit. As U could see on the picture below (top-right corner) the lights are only a polygons with an emission material applied - that could be seen on the right. Set the power of light as U need and done!

[image]

Hope it helps my buddy, Jan.